# How to achieve high availability for Active Directory LDAPS (Secure LDAP)

Tags: ldap

We have around 50 applications currently configured with LDAP and we have around 20 Domain Controllers. As per the security best practice we have to migrate all these applications from LDAP to LDPAS.
Currently, all applications are connected using Domain's "NETBIOS" name so there no need to worry about high availability.

What is the best design approach to achieve high availability for LDAPS?

Prefer not to configure individual DC servers as LDAPS servers in the application.
Note: all the servers (DC and application servers) are enrolled in on-prem PKI.

Answer (score 0):

In my enterprise environment, there is a load balancer with a virtual IP which distributes traffic accross multiple DCs. Clients access ad.example.com, and each DC behind ad.example.com has a cert valid both for hostname.example.com and ad.example.com (SAN, subject alternative name). This has the advantage of allowing the load balancer to manage which hosts are up -- if a target does not respond on port 636, it is automatically removed from the virtual IP. When the target begins responding, it is automatically added back. LDAP clients don't need to do anything unusual to use this high availability AD LDAPS solution. The down side is that the server admin has ongoing maintenance as DCs are replaced -- we build a new server and then remove the old one. In doing so, the old IP is retired. The new IP needs to be added to the load balancer virtual IP config.

Another approach would be to use DNS to find the domain controllers -- there are SRV records registered both for the Site domain controllers and all domain controllers. Something like _ldap.tcp.SiteName._sites.example.com will give you the DCs in example.com's SiteName site. For all DCs in the example.com domain, look up _ldap._tcp.example.com ... this approach, however, requires the LDAP client to be modified to perform the DNS lookups. The advantage of this approach is that the DCs manage their DNS entries. No one needs to remember to add a new DC to the DNS service records.